# Flask: [405 error] with pagination and POST request

Tags: python, flask, pagination

I have a Flask app with a route that uses pagination and has to handle GET and POST requests.
I defined two routes for my function as described [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/44/)
to get the pagination working.

When I post a form on a page other than the first then I get a

> "405 - Method Not Allowed" error.

How can I handle this?
I am using `peewee` for my database.

Here is the flask app code:

```
@app.route("/tiles/failed", defaults={"page": 1}, methods=["POST", "GET"])
@app.route("/tiles/failed/page/<int:page>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def tiles_failed(page):
    if request.method == "POST":
        process_id, tile_name = request.form["tile_name"].split("/")
        select_status = request.form["select_status"]
        if not select_status == "False":
            process = models.Process.select().where(models.Process.id == process_id).get()
            tile = models.Tile.select().where(models.Tile.name == tile_name and models.Tile.process == process).get()
            tile.message = "Manual state change from '{from_state}' to '{to_state}'".format(from_state=tile.success,
                                                                                            to_state=select_status)
            tile.success = select_status
            tile.error_count = 0
            tile.save()
    all_tiles = models.Tile.select().where(models.Tile.success == "False").order_by(models.Tile.name, models.Tile.process)
    count = all_tiles.count()
    tiles = get_tiles_per_page(all_tiles, page, TILES_PER_PAGE, count)
    if not tiles and page != 1:
        abort(404)
    pagination = Pagination(page, TILES_PER_PAGE, count)
    t = app.jinja2_env.get_template("tiles.html")
    return t.render(tiles=tiles, pagination=pagination, count=count, request=request)
```

here is the relevant HTML snippet:

```
<form name="select_form" method="post">
  <select name="select_status" onchange="if(confirm('are you sure?')){this.form.submit();}else{selectFalse();}">
    <option value="False" selected>False</option>
    <option value="True">True</option>
    <option value="pending">pending</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="tile_name" value="{{ tile.process.id }}/{{ tile.name }}" />
</form>
```

Hopefully this explains my problem.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form must have an `action` attribute which points to the function which handles the form. In your case this function is `tiles_failed`:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('tiles_failed') }}" name="select_form" method="post">
```

Comment: Thank you! That answered my question. I may need to add an extra function for that POST request.

Comment: Glad to help. You can now accept the answer to close the question.